# Saving drop-down menu to SQLite database in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

Having some trouble here, hopefully someone can help. I have a drop-down menu that I am able to to get the data from the field, only when the save function fires off, it doesn't save it, the info is blank. I tried to set it up that the function returned the string, only I'm taking in an int to show the selection number, so it's not compatible. Any thoughts? Yes, the string is public.

```
public string GetDropSelection(int index)
 {
     Debug.Log(index);
     switch (index)
     {
         case 1: BrakeWheelField="Front";
         break;

         case 2: BrakeWheelField="Rear";
         break;

         case 3: BrakeWheelField="Both";
         break;
     }
     return BrakeWheelField; //I know this technique doesn't work because what is coming in is not what's going out.
     Debug.Log("What is the selection?" + BrakeWheelField); //Variable has the value here.
 }

 public void GetBrakeData(string BrakeWheelField)
 {
     Debug.Log(BrakeWheelField); //By the time it gets to here, it's blank.

     BrakeDateofPurchaseField=BrakeDateofPurchaseText.text;
     BrakeMileageField=BrakeMileageText.text;
     BrakeLocationField=BrakeLocationText.text;
     BrakeLaborField=BrakeLaborText.text;
     BrakeBrandField= BrakeBrandText.text;
     BrakePriceField= BrakePriceText.text;
     BrakeNotesField = BrakeNotesText.text;

     DatabaseManager.Instance.SQLiteInit();
     DatabaseManager.Instance.SaveBrakeInfo(BrakeDateofPurchaseField, BrakeMileageField, BrakeLocationField, BrakeLaborField, BrakeBrandField, BrakePriceField, BrakeWheelField, BrakeNotesField);

 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might create a unit test for your methods, to verify if you give them the correct values they return the expected answers, and what they do if given invalid input. Lookup "unity unit tests" for more information.

Comment: It's really hard to debug your code for you, when we don't see more of what could be causing the error. IE we don't see how `GroupDropSelection` is called, and what receives the returned string. And what goes on between `GroupDropSelection` and `GetBrakeData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your switch statement a `default` to see if you are getting an index other than 1, 2 or 3 - like so.

```
 switch (index)
 {
     case 1: BrakeWheelField="Front";
     break;

     case 2: BrakeWheelField="Rear";
     break;

     case 3: BrakeWheelField="Both";
     break;

     default:
          Debug.Log("GroupDropSelection invalid index: "+index);
     break;
 }
```

Or add the default to one of your other cases, if you want it to default to that answer. Such as

```
 switch (index)
 {
     default: // Make "Front" the default for other cases than 1,2or3
     case 1: BrakeWheelField="Front";
     break;

     case 2: BrakeWheelField="Rear";
     break;

     case 3: BrakeWheelField="Both";
     break;
 }
```

Separate answer, but I'll keep it in the same post.

`BrakeWheelField` in `GetBrakeData` is not your global variable, but is the local variable passed in the argument to `GetBrakeData`. If you give `GetBrakeData` an empty value, then so will be the `BrakeWheelField` in the method. In the `Debug.Log`, if you precede `BrakeWheelData` with `this.` you will get the global value. See my edit:

```
public void GetBrakeData(string BrakeWheelField)
 {
     Debug.Log(BrakeWheelField); // GetBrakeData's local BrakeWheelField
     Debug.Log(this.BrakeWheelField); // the global value for BrakeWheelField

     BrakeDateofPurchaseField=BrakeDateofPurchaseText.text;
     BrakeMileageField=BrakeMileageText.text;
     BrakeLocationField=BrakeLocationText.text;
     BrakeLaborField=BrakeLaborText.text;
     BrakeBrandField= BrakeBrandText.text;
     BrakePriceField= BrakePriceText.text;
     BrakeNotesField = BrakeNotesText.text;

     DatabaseManager.Instance.SQLiteInit();
     DatabaseManager.Instance.SaveBrakeInfo(BrakeDateofPurchaseField, BrakeMileageField, BrakeLocationField, BrakeLaborField, BrakeBrandField, BrakePriceField, BrakeWheelField, BrakeNotesField);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck! I take it that I must do something similar on the singleton. At present, it's not saving, but it did come through the GetBrakeData function.

Comment: Chuck, you were right! I had to add a this.BrakeWheelField when I inserted into the database as well as on the singleton. Then it worked!